Covering properties of non-constant holomorphic function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
I'm working through a proof that Riemann surfaces are second countable, and one of the main steps is showing that if $X$ is a connected Riemann surface such that there is a non-constant holomorphic function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, then $X$ is second-countable.
One of the steps I am confused about is that if $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a basis open set, then we can consider the components of $f^{-1}(U)$ that are finite covers of their images and ramified at at most one point. Why should there be such components that are finite covers, and how do we know they are ramified at at most one point?
Another similar confusion is that afterwards we can then consider a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x \in X$ that maps to $f(U_x)$ by a finite-sheeted covering map. This is how we construct a basis for $X$. Again I am not sure why such a neighborhood exists and why the covering is finite.
So my primary confusion is why $f$ has what seems to be finite covering space properties at least locally. My current source is Hubbard's Teichmuller Theory.
